# visual studio android emulator NFC

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator, nfc, rfid

I have installed Visual Studio Android Emulator in Dell tablet Venue 8 pro 5855. The OS is Windows 10 pro and came with built-in NFC. But I did not see any NFC settings in the additional tools.

Is NFC supported in Visual Studio Android Emulator?

Looking for some inputs. Thanks in advance!

This is the screenshot of the emulator's additional tools

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to have:
1- The open NFC (sdk addon)
2-The Open NFC core (last version is 4.5.2)
you can download from [here](http://open-nfc.org/wp/home/downloads/)

Comment: hi @khalilM can you explain more detail? I don't really understand. Have you tried it before and does it work?